# Flask API - validate hash request

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In my flask API application I want to validate a hash sent by a client. If a client sends an incorrect hash I would like to return immediately an error message.
The hash is generated by a predefined calculation shared by the client and my application.

In the example below it's instantiated in the `Controller` class returning the result of `new_configuration`.

What is the best way to validate the hash (considering that I have multiple methods like this) in a clean, elegant and centralized manner without using if statements for each method?

```
@app.route('/newRegistration', methods=['POST'])
def new_registration():

    controller = Controller()
    return jsonify(controller.new_configuration(request.json))
```

Note: all my route methods call the `Controller` class.

Answer (score 1):

Flask has `before_request`, `after_request` and more features that can help you manage that.

Use example:

```
# routes that won't be hash validated 
PUBLIC_ROUTES = ["/favicon.ico", "/"]

@app.before_request
def validate_hash():
    # avoid validating on public routes
    for route in PUBLIC_ROUTES:
        if route == request.path:
            return

    hash = g.params.get("hash", None)

    # validate hash exists in request
    if not hash:
        raise BadRequestError("Missing hash")

    if hash != DEFAULT_HASH:
        raise UnauthorizedError("Hash is invalid")
```

before each request to the flask routes which are not declared in `PUBLIC_ROUTES` the method will be executed and will try to validate the hash parameter received in the request

about your note, you can add another `before_request` that init the controller and use `flask.g` feature to pass it to the other routes in your flow.